# createImageBitmap alternative on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, image, safari, web-worker

I'd like to generate images in a bit of asm.js code running on a web worker. And I'd like to regularly composite the latest state of that computation onto a user-visible 2d canvas, together with some other content. Currently I have code which

1. constructs an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object using [its constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData), based on a portion of the array buffer used by the asm.js code,
2. calls [`createImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapFactories/createImageBitmap) to turn the `ImageData` into an [`ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap),
3. [transfers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) that image bitmap from the worker to the GUI thread and
4. uses that `ImageBitmap` as an argument to [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Things work nicely in recent Chrome and Firefox, but Safari 9.1.3 apparently has no `createImageBitmap` function. **How would I do something like the above in a way that works on Safari?**

Is there some low-cost encoding of images, short of creating a `data:image/png…` for it? Is there some other way to turn a byte array into something you can feed to `drawImage`?

By the way: http://caniuse.com/ currently doesn't list this feature. There is [a feature request](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/2801) which you can  if you would like to see this feature monitored there.

---

If you prefer to see code for my current approach, here is the relevant portion of my worker:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bufferSize);
var asm = Module.asm(self, {}, buffer);
var imgBytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer, offset);
var imgData = new ImageData(imgBytes, width, height);
createImageBitmap(imgData).then(function(bmp) { // Not available on Safari!
    postMessage(bmp, [bmp]);
});
```

and here the corresponding GUI thread code:

```
var worker = new Worker(‹url of worker›);
worker.onmessage = function(msg) {
    var img = msg.data;
    context2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
};
```

The actual unabridged code is in [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/CindyJS/CindyJS/pull/517), but there is a lot of other stuff which is irrelevant for the question at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some other way to turn a byte array into something you can
>   feed to `drawImage`?

You can post the `ArrayBuffer` of `Uint8ClampedArray` object to main thread; at main thread substitute using `.putImageData()` for `.drawImage()`. As indicated by @Kaiido, it is not necessary to create an `ImageData` object at `Worker`

```
var imgBytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer, offset);
postMessage(imgBytes.buffer, [imgBytes.buffer]);
```

at main thread

```
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(e.data); // `ArrayBuffer`
  ctx.putImageData(new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(e.data), width, height), 0, 0);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/N0v1YQHQX2rdFfHcOKeR?p=preview

Comment: This loads the image from a PNG file. So while it is stored in a typed array, it's not raw pixel data. If I were to duplicate this approach, I'd likely have to PNG-encode the pixel data, which takes some time and requires either some libraries or some self-written code for PNG headers, row header insertion and minimal deflate encoding (e.g. using only the uncompressed store method). Still, it might be a viable option, particularly if nothing better turns up, so thanks!

Comment: @MvG You can alternatively transfer the `buffer` of `imgData` to main thread at `postMessage`, substitute using `.putImageData` for `.drawImage`; see updated post.

Comment: If I follow correctly, for your last part, you don't need to create an ImageData Object in the worker (https://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/234ekx4b/)

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, you are correct. http://plnkr.co/edit/N0v1YQHQX2rdFfHcOKeR?p=preview\

Comment: This sounds interesting. Since I need to composite with other content, I need `drawImage`, but I can `putImageData` to an off-screen canvas and then `drawImage` that to the primary.