# Display image from ID3 image data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob, cloudinary, id3

I've tried all of the methods I could find in stackoverflow. This two are some of the most complete posts:

[Display image from blob using javascript and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089732/display-image-from-blob-using-javascript-and-websockets)

[How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript/246813#246813)

> I'm using cloudinary and id3js. First I upload the mp3 file to
>   cloudinary, then I request the file with Ajax through id3js. This
>   gives me all of the ID3 tags.

```
  openUploadModal() {
      cloudinary.openUploadWidget(window.cloudinaryOptions,
      (errors, track) => {
          if(!values(errors).length) {

              id3(track[0].secure_url, (errs, tags) => {
                  this.setState({
                      title: tags.title,
                      audio_url: track[0].secure_url,
                      artist: tags.artist,
                      uploaded: true,
                      cover_photo: this.getImage(tags.v2.image)
                   });
               });
           }
      });
  }
```

And the image converter:

```
getImage(image) {
    var arrayBuffer = image.data;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    return  "data:image/png;base64,"+btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(bytes)));
}
```

This is what the tags object looks like:

[image]

I then use the return value of getImage in the background-image attribute of a div. There are no errors in the console (not a bad request) but when opening the data:image/jpg;base64,... link there's only a little white square on the page.

**How can I get a working url from the image object in the ID3 tags?**

Comment: `Uint8Array` is not a string. Is `image.data` an `ArrayBuffer` of image, or `ImageData` instance?

Answer (score 0):

If `image.data` is an `ArrayBuffer`, you can use `FileReader`. `FileReader` `load` event is asynchronous, you cannot return the result from the function without using `Promise`, though you can use `FileReaderSync()` at `Worker`.

See also [createImageBitmap alternative on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094245/createimagebitmap-alternative-on-safari/).

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  // do stuff with `data URI` of `image.data`
  console.log(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([image.data], {type:image.mime}));
```

Comment: I tried this but the data URI still shows only an empty white square. Same mp3 file in soundcloud displays the embedded image correctly. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: @SebastianCruz Is a return value expected from `getImage()`? `FileReader` `load` event returns results asynchronously at `load` event handler.

Comment: See [ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string) for synchronous solutions to convert `ArrayBuffer` to `base64` string.

Comment: I was not expecting a return value from `getImage()`. I used the `reader.result` data to set the `cover_photo` of `this.state` in `reader.onload`. It does successfully return a data:image/jpg;base64,... string but no image is shown. I tried the approach in the article you posted and I got the same result.

Comment: How is the `ArrayBuffer` created? Can you reproduce `javascript` at Question at plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: I'm not sure how the `ArrayBuffer` is created. That's just what id3.js returns when extracting the data from the ID3 tags in the mp3 file. Here is the code related to the question [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qqs2G6C5iVx3IZLvU0IA?p=catalogue).

Comment: `javascript` at plnkr link is incomplete, see http://stackoverflow.com/mcve

Comment: The issue appears to be other than script which converts `ArrayBuffer` to `data URI` http://plnkr.co/edit/nipEpqITUb1YqP9ckvub?p=preview. Is `type` correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135541/discussion-between-sebastian-cruz-and-guest271314).