# Would the image like progressive jpeg or webp be decode in the web worker and not in main thread when the image is fetched via web worker

Tags: javascript, fetch, web-worker

```
fetch('abc.webp')
    .then(processStatus)
        .then(parseBlob)
            .then(myBlob => {
                  var objURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
            });
```

and then just send this image to the main worker to render on the page?
If not so then how would I do it so that the image be decoded in the worker thread and then sent to main thread for rendering.

Comment: Yes, `Worker` has its own scope.

Comment: So that means that if I download an image in web worker than it would download and decode that image or video blob and then pass it to the main thread? 
Am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes. See [WorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope)

Comment: You can convert the image to an `ArrayBuffer` and transfer the buffer to the main thread, see  [createImageBitmap alternative on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094245/createimagebitmap-alternative-on-safari/)